# Fixed table header <td> width on IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement which has been successfully implemented on IE6 and not working as expected in IE8. The description is as follows: 
     A table is having a fixed header with vertical and horizontal scroll.Horizontal scroll is necessary as it has many columns,about 20. On horizontal scroll the header is not fixed, however on vertical it is fixed. 
Technically this is done using 2 tables,1st table acts as a header and the 2nd acts as content.Also I am calculating the TD width dynamically and setting the width using JAVASCRIPT.
Now the table width is not visible on IE8. I have found this out as a CSS issue,although I am not sure where the error is exactly placed. Looking forward on this.

```
//Function to set cell width of table containing header and the table containing content in synch.
function setTableColumnWidth(table1, table2) {

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        var tablecell1 = document.getElementById(table1).rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
        var tablecell2 = document.getElementById(table2).rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
        if (tablecell1 > tablecell2) {
            document.getElementById(table2).rows[0].cells[i].style.width = tablecell1;


        } else {
            document.getElementById(table1).rows[0].cells[i].style.width = tablecell2;


        }
        if (i == 20) {
            var table1col12 = document.getElementById(table1).rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
            document.getElementById(table1).rows[0].cells[i].style.width = table1col12 + 20;

        }

    }
}
function checkTable(table1, table2) {
    if (document.getElementById(table1).rows[0] != null
            && document.getElementById(table2).rows[0] != null) {
        setTableColumnWidth(table1, table2);
    }
}
```

This is the JS code. However I dont think this has a problem.

Comment: I dont have answer but I have advice. You shouldn't hack IE's layout with JS because 1-2% ( 50-100 people out of 5000 ) without JS, will see it all properly messed up.

Comment: Looking forward for some code and an example @ [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - that would be awsome :)

Comment: @Sean, I don't agree. Today almost any website requires js (like SO), ajax, tabs, widgets, map applications etc. are everywhere... And people who have javascript switched off are hackers who know very well what happens and can turn it on. BTW it won't be even whole 1% of people, it's just 1-2% of **sessions** (these people are more active, maybe also robots & scripts are included in these stats).

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs, CSS widths are supposed to have units. E.g. `cell.style.width = "443"` is not correct, that should be `cell.style.width = "443px"`.
If you're sure you're measuring in pixels, you can use the table cell's width attribute. That's `cell.width` without the `style`. (Those attributes are numbers without units, just like offsetWidth.)

As to why it works in IE6 but not in IE8, that is because IE8 adheres to the standards better.